# Weird ajax remember me login bug

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This just came up: when I attempt to log in via ajax, for some strange reason `Username field is not set` is printed but the username is clearly set.

```
   <?php
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../inc/inc.all.php');
$username;
$password;
$remember;
$token;

if (!isset($_POST['username'])) {
    echo "Username field must be set!";
    die();
}
$username = $_POST['username'];

if (!isset($_POST['password'])) {
    echo "Password field must be set";
    die();
}
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$remember = $_POST['remember'];

if (!isset($_POST['token'])) {
    echo "There was a problem logging you in securly, Prehaps you are trying to log in from a different window?";
    die();
} else {
    $token = $_POST['token'];
}

// Validate token
if (!isset($token) || $token != $_SESSION['token']) {
    echo "Invalid token: There was a problem logging you in securley, Prehaps you are trying to log in from a different window?";
    die();
}

// Log the user in
$sql = "SELECT ID FROM cs_users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND password = '{$password}'";
$query = $db -> query($sql);
if ($query -> num_rows) {
    list($id) = @array_values($query -> fetch_assoc());
    if ($remember) {
        $expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 180;
        echo $id.'<br>'.$username.'<br>'.$password.'<br>';
        setcookie("id", $id, $expire);
        setcookie("username", $username, $expire);
        setcookie("password", $password, $expire);
        header("LOCATION:{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    }
    echo true;
} else {
    echo "Invalid username/password";
    die();
}
?>
```

In the above code, if I change _POST to _GET and access the page via `login.php?username=mrkirby153&password=admin&remember=true&token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` it still says that the field is unset. (Yes I know there are some major security "breaches" in my code. I am working on fixing it.)

---

`var_dump($_POST)`: array(0){}

Html form

```
<div id="login">
        <div id="login-err"></div>
        <label for="username">Username: </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="loginUsername" placeholder="Username">
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="loginPass" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="button" name="loginBttn" id="loginSubmit" class="btn btn-success" value="Log in" onclick="userLogin()">
        <br>
        <label for="remember">Remember me?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="loginRemember">
        <br>
        <a href="forgot">Forgot login credentials?</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="token" id="loginToken" value="<?php echo $token?>">
    </div>
```

Method used to ajax:

```
function userLogin() {

    var username = $("#loginUsername").val();
    var password = $("#loginPass").val();
    var remember = $("#loginRemember").is(':checked');
    var token = $("#loginToken").val();
    alert(username);
    $(".ajax-loader").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#login").slideUp("slow");

    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "internal/CloudShop/ajax/login.php",
        dataType : "html",
        data : "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&remember=" + remember + "&token=" + token,
        success : function(result) {

            if (result != "1") {
                $("#login-err").html(result);
                $("#login").slideDown("slow");
            } else
                location.reload();
            $(".ajax-loader").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });

}
```

Sitenote: It still sets the cookie though and I'm logged in if i refresh the page

Comment: Can you post your HTML form please?

Comment: Add `var_dump($_POST)` and look at the result.

Comment: @Barmar it prints out array(0){}

Comment: Try changing Get to POST in the ajax call.

Comment: @Pjack Didn't work if remember me is checked

Comment: Can you look in the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what parameters are being sent?

Comment: @Barmar firebug (in firefox) reports that the post data to login.php is username=mrkirby153&password=****&remember=true&token=xxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Something in your script must be overwriting `$_POST`, since it's correct when AJAX sends the parameters.

Comment: @Barmar I've made some modifications to the code (not using globals) and if I put `echo $sql; die();` after I define the SQL query, the program runs through just file and echos out `SELECT ID FROM cs_users WHERE username ='mrkirby153' and password = 'md5PasswordHash'` It doesn't return the username not set error

Comment: I've never used `$GLOBALS`, I'm not sure why changing that would have this effect. You don't use `register_globals`, do you?

Comment: @Barmar I have found the problem! For some reason the ajax is both POSTing and GETting. That's why it is saying the username is not set!

Comment: @Barmar I *think* I fixed it :) And the button isn't in a form

Comment: Weird. If it's not in a form, I'm at a total loss to explain where the POST is coming from. The GET comes from `type: "GET"` in AJAX.

Comment: Do you have a click handler on any containing elements that also submits something? It could be due to event bubbling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. After setting the cookie, I was executing `header("LOCATION:{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");` which would re-call the login form again but without any `$_POST` data

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `data` parameter to:

```
data : { username: username,
         password: password,
         remember: remember ? 'true' : 'false',
         token: token
       },
```

jQuery will then encode the parameters properly.

The reason your form is being submitted twice is presumably because the normal form submission is happening after `userLogin()` returns. Change your submit button to:

```
<input type="button" name="loginBttn" id="loginSubmit" class="btn btn-success" value="Log in" onclick="userLogin(); return false;">
```

Returning `false` from the submit button disables the default action.